# Play Sound When Typing in WebView Android

Tags: java, android, webview, onclick, soundpool

Currently, I am still in the proccess of learning Android development, so please excuse me if this question of mine is not easily understandable.

I have created an Android app that use WebView and I want to know how to enable sound when I typing in WebView within my app.

So far I only able to enable the sound when clicking a website link in WebView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my WebView code.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    String url = "www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
    
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        } else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }
    
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                soundOn();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    ...

    private void soundOn() {
        SoundPool sp = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(5)
                .build();

        sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int i, int i1) {
                soundPool.play(i, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        });

        sp.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mysound, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-You first create a custom class from web view like the one below:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {


public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new BaseInputConnection(this, false); //this is needed for #dispatchKeyEvent() to be notified.
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    //return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    boolean dispatchFirst = super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    // Listening here for whatever key events you need
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
                soundOn();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                // e.g. get enter events here
                break;
            // case other keys

        }
    return dispatchFirst;
}
```

}

2-Then go to layout and replace your WebView class:

```
            <com...CustomWebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />
```

Comment: Nima, what is the proper method to make a sound when I click a link in WebView? Right now I am using shouldoverrideurlloading to make the sound. But the problem is sometime when I click a website link, I hear the click sound 2 times.

Comment: You log in to this method and see how many times this method is executed. It may be repeated twice for some links. Which you can do with methods like handler. Pause for a few seconds

Comment: NIma, would you mind sharing the method? I don't know how to apply it. I have sent you an email.

Comment: ok i checked it